# Enable OpenMP checks and flags in autoconf and automake

Tags: openmp, autotools, autoconf, automake

I cannot for the life of me find any information on the internet about using openMP with the autotools! I find vague references to macros like AC_OPENMP and AX_OPENMP, neither of which work. AC_OPENMP causes a "possibly undefined macro error". AX_OPENMP gets past autoconf, but causes configure to complain that AX_OPENMP is undefined. It is my understanding that these macros should check for openMP and set OPENMP_CFLAGS to the appropriate value.

Over in my Makefile.am, I can't even get foo_CXXFLAGS (it's a C++ project) to work right for OpenMP. If I manually set `foo_CXXFLAGS = -fopenmp` in Makefile.am, the -fopenmp flag is added to all the compile commands except for the (link) stage that combines the object files together, of course causing undefined reference errors. This one may be my misunderstanding. setting `AM_CXXFLAGS = -fopenmp` works, but its not the best thing to do. Actually neither is setting foo_CXXFLAGS without checking but I can't seem to get that to work.

Please, can anyone help me here? This seems like such a simple, common task that there ought to be oodles of documentation out there on the web about it. To clarify a few things, yes, the code compiles fine if I do it manually, and it runs without error. It's only in this autoconfiscating stage that things are screwing up. If you could point me to documentation on using openMP with autoconf, you'd be my new best buddy. Thanks.

Autoconf version 2.59, automake version 1.9.6

Comment: `AX_` is the namespace for external macros. If you want `AX_OPENMP` to be defined, you'll have to download it and include it in your m4 directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As to your first question regarding "possibly undefined macro error", `AC_OPENMP` was added to autoconf in 2.62, so you'll need to upgrade.  As to the second question, if you want a flag added at linktime, you want to specify it in `AM_LDFLAGS`

Comment: No need to add a flag to AM_LDFLAGS. Just use `AC_LANG(C++);AC_PROG_CXX;AC_OPENMP;AC_SUBST(AM_CXXFLAGS,"$OPENMP_CXXFLAGS <other flags>")`. This will insert `-fopenmp` in both compilation and link commands.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's plenty of years late, but this answer may help anyone having the same problem.

I was tryng to get to work libtiff and OpenMP together with Automake. This following lines did the trick for me in src/Makefile.am (ignore the libtiff):

```
foo_CFLAGS += $(LIBTIFF_CFLAGS) -fopenmp
foo_LDFLAGS = -fopenmp
foo_LDADD   = $(LIBTIFF_LIBS)
```